# MVVM way to allow data to be displayed in many different ways in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an application that parses a user's data and displays information about it in DataGrids using WPF. However each user only wants certain fields displayed for each grid.

Right now I'm using multiple datagrids for each table and choosing one to display with an enum.

What's the best way to avoid having a lot of duplicate xaml code, and to allow for the addition of new configurations while obeying the MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 1):

The `Column` of the `DataGrid` supports a `Visibility` property which can be either visible or collapsed.

You can bind this property to a field in the viewmodel, so your viewmodel can control which columns are visible and which are not visible.

You can even write converters that will convert the `enum` that you already have to a `Visibility` value for any given column, thus sparing your viewmodel from nitty-gritty presentation concerns, as per the MVVM paradigm.

Comment: Certainly a valid answer, but one thing to remember when you do this is that hidden/collapsed items are still part of the visible tree, you just can't see them. If you have a lot of data to display then for performance reasons it's best to not have those hidden elements there at all, which is why Data Templating...or using DataTriggers to set the template...is preferable IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably get flagged for not having enough focus. It's very dependent on that exact nature of the data you're trying to display, and even then it tends to be very opinion-based.

That said, if you want to change the appearance based on the type of data then you typically use [Data Templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview), whereas if you want the display to change based on the value of a known type (or types) then you usually use [Data Triggers](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/).

Comment: What properties of the data are relevant here for a more focused question?